# ApplicationContext beanfactory org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: java, spring

```
 UserAccountServiceImpl service = applicationContext.getBean("UserAccountServiceImpl", UserAccountServiceImpl.class);
 service =SpringContextListener.getBean("UserAccountServiceImpl", UserAccountServiceImpl.class);
```

my code is like above.
I invoke getBean in two ways.The first way ran perfact,but the second one throw an exception like this

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'UserAccountServiceImpl' is defined

applictionContext is got from `implements ApplicationContextAware`
SpringContextListener is like below:

```
 <bean id="springContextListener" class="com.xxxx.xxx.SpringContextListener"/>
```

---

```
public final class SpringContextListener implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private static BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public static BeanFactory getBeanFactory() {
        return beanFactory;
    }

    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        if(SpringContextListener.beanFactory != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("beanFactory inited .............");
        }
        SpringContextListener.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> clazs) {  
        return clazs.cast(beanFactory.getBean(beanName));  
    }  
}
```

what is the difference between applicationContext and beanfactory?what is my code's problem ?

Comment: Your code isn't complete. You're not calling `SpringContextListener.setBeanFactory` anywhere. The question makes no sense without that.

Comment: Have you define the `UserAccountServiceImpl` bean yet in your application context? or is it should be `UserAccountService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `UserAccountServiceImpl` as bean in application-context.xml

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext =
    newClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

UserAccountServiceImpl service = applicationContext.getBean("UserAccountServiceImpl",
    UserAccountServiceImpl.class);

System.out.println(service);

service=SpringContextListener.getBean("UserAccountServiceImpl",UserAccountServImpl.class);

System.out.println(service);
```

Result:

```
UserAccountServiceImpl [toString()=com.vl.test.UserAccountServiceImpl@3834d63f]
UserAccountServiceImpl [toString()=com.vl.test.UserAccountServiceImpl@3834d63f]
```

Comment: added in application-context.xml like below:                                                        <bean id="UserAccountServiceImpl" class="com.vl.test.UserAccountServiceImpl" />

Comment: Thank you!your answer is right to sovle my problem.But not the exact result i want.Finally,i know the reason.<context:component-scan base-package="com.yl" /> this tag should be add before  UserAccountServiceImpl getting the beanfactory!